# React-Dnd - how to control drag preview position relative to cursor and get drop location relative to drop target

Tags: react-dnd

I'm trying to build a resource scheduling app, where you can drag a task item from one list onto a grid. The grid's rows represent the "resource" (a person) and the columns represent time of day (broken up into 15-minute intervals). 
I've made good progress using React-Dnd but there are some annoying UX issues I'm struggling to fix. The first is the drag preview. I'd like to use a custom component as the drag preview. The React-Dnd documentation explains how to do that. But what I can't figure out is how to force the preview to be positioned such that the cursor is at the top-left corner of the drag preview. The reason for this is so that it's clear to the user where they are really dropping the thing. Suppose the user wants to drop a task at "1:00pm". They may naturally try to line up the left edge of the preview with the left edge of the "1:00pm" column. But if the mouse is actually positioned over the "1:30pm" column, then that's where it'll be dropped. I think that this problem can be avoided by simply positioning the mouse cursor at the upper-left edge of the drag preview. Is that possible?

Another related problem is that I would ideally like to know the coordinates of the drop location relative to the row "View" that it was dropped into. I've been working with iOS for the past 2 years so I'm thinking in terms of the coordinate system on iOS. Maybe that way of thinking doesn't translate to the DOM, I don't know. But if there's some way to know the x-position of the drop relative to the left edge of the row itself (not of the page or screen), then I can figure out what column (i.e., which time-of-day interval) the thing was dropped on.

Is it possible to do these things with React-Dnd (or any other React drag & drop libraries)?

Comment: One of my problems was that I wasn't aware that the Event clientX and clientY values are always relative to the _viewport_. I was trying to use those values as *left* and *top* values for absolute-positioned elements, and that just doesn't work. The coordinates have to be translated with the help of Element.getBoundingClientRect(). I ended up dropping React-Dnd in favor of React-Rnd and some custom coding. I'll add a more detailed explanation and my solution later.

Comment: This article was helpful https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3441-translating-viewport-coordinates-into-element-local-coordinates-using-element-getboundingclientrect.htm